# How to use an object as a data source c#

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm trying to figure out how to make an object data source where I can select which columns to display in Visual Studio and all that. Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do?

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ManuPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string ListID { get; set; }
    public string VendorRef { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public string EditSequence { get; set; }
    public string UPC { get; set; }
}
public class ItemDataSource : IEnumerable<ItemData>
{
    private ICollection<ItemData> list;
    public ItemDataSource()
    {
        try
        {
            list = QBCom.GetItemList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            list = new List<ItemData>();
        }
    }
    public ItemDataSource(IEnumerable<ItemData> data)
    {
        list = data.ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerator<ItemData> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<ItemData>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I am not talking about ASP.net, I'm talking about stuff like DataTables and so forth. Just a regular winforms program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to bind to a DataGridView if so I would inherit from BindingSource and set the list to the DataSource.  You can then set the datagridview DataSource to the object to view the columns in the visual studio properties window.

```
public class ItemDataSource : BindingSource
{
    private ICollection<ItemData> list;
    public ItemDataSource()
    {
        try
        {
            list = QBCom.GetItemList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            list = new List<ItemData>();
        }
        this.DataSource = list;
    }
    public ItemDataSource(IEnumerable<ItemData> data)
    {
        list = data.ToList();
        this.DataSource = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why, but even the example I posted seems to work. So now I know two ways. I think I like this one better though, it seems like it'd be more extendable. :D